# Why can't I run my batch file with elevated privilege?

Tags: windows

I have a batch file that I want to run with elevated privilege and I have created a link and checked the option run as administrator but it doesn't work? I have Windows 8 and disabled UAC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compile your batch file into an .exe with administrative rights

bat-2-exe worked for me when I needed to accomplish this

Comment: Have you tried ' runas '

Comment: RUNAS [/profile] [/env] [/netonly] /user:user Program

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811372/how-to-code-a-bat-file-to-always-run-as-admin-mode

Comment: ^^There is an answer in this topic that may be of some use

Comment: I tested elevate program from the link. it works. Thanks